# Perl: Get value from XML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I need to get value from this xml - http://pastebin.com/wkh7trd4. Here is my code, but it return nothing:

```
my $xml = XML::LibXML->new('clean_namespaces' => 1)->parse_file("$tmp_dir/xml/$xml_file_name");
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xml);
my $val = $xc->findvalue('/ns2:export/ns2:bankGuarantee/docPublishDate');
print $val;
```

Comment: It may be throwing an exception, wrap it in an eval{} and dump $@ if it exists

Comment: would be interested to see an answer to this that explains the issue as from your code it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has to do with default name space. Not sure how xpath works but @miller seemed to answer his own question here: [XML::LibXML, namespaces and findvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419772/xmllibxml-namespaces-and-findvalue)

You can try the below which should hopefully resolve your issue

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

open(my $xml_file, '<', "xml_to_parse.xml");
my $xml = new XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => $xml_file);
print $xml->findvalue('/ns2:export/ns2:bankGuarantee/*[local-name()="docPublishDate"]'), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

libraries often throw exceptions on failure, if you do not catch them, they could fail silently.

try:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

eval
{
    my $xml = XML::LibXML->new('clean_namespaces' => 1)->parse_file("$tmp_dir/xml/$xml_file_name");
    my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xml);
    my $val = $xc->findvalue('/ns2:export/ns2:bankGuarantee/docPublishDate');
    print $val;
}
if($@)
{
    print "ERROR: " . $@;
}
```

If one is failing, it should give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just creating an `XML::LibXML:XPathContext` object won't make any difference, you also need to register all the namespaces that you want to use in your XPath expressions. In this case you've used the `ns2` namespace without registering any namespaces at all

Your code should look something like this

```
my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("$tmp_dir/xml/$xml_file_name");

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xml);
$xc->RegisterNs( ns2 => 'http://example.com/ns2/uri/address');

my $val = $xc->findvalue('/ns2:export/ns2:bankGuarantee/docPublishDate');
print $val;
```

Note that the URI you register has to match the one in the

```
xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2/uri/address"
```

attribute in the data

I'm wondering if the `clean_namespaces` parser option is your attempt to fix this? `clean_namespaces` will only remove *redundant* namespaces, i.e. those that aren't used anywhere in the XML document. There's little point in doing that as you stand little chance of the namespaces clashing, and the time and memory saved will be negligible